# what configuration to be made to run phoneGap app in android and IOS both?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform

I am developing one cross plateform app .. so that i want it to be run on android and IOS both.

so i want to know that what configuration to be made in phonegap to run app in both android and iOS

Comment: Supported by default, unless you do something platform-specific. There's no real master-list of platform-specific things -- http://caniuse.com will be of some use as to what works on what platform's webview, while Cordova has documented quirks as to differences that exist between platforms for plugins and such. Reading the docs (http://docs.cordova.io) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create the app

```
cordova create yourApp
```

Then you add the platforms

```
cordova platform add ios android
```

That's all, now you can run you app on ios or android using

```
cordova run android
```

or

```
cordova run ios
```